# Can cucumber automation testing be used to test Java Applications?

Tags: java, cucumber

Can we use cucumber automation testing to test a Java Application ? 
I am working on a client server model and my Client is a Java application, so i wanted to know if cucumber can be used to test my client (java) ?

Thanks in advance for your reply :)

Comment: The fact that there's a Stack Overflow tag for `cucumber-java` should be a big clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Please have a look: https://pragprog.com/book/srjcuc/the-cucumber-for-java-book

Comment: Thank you Zaki :)

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber is not the testing tool itself, but it's the **BDD framework** that helps to create easy mapping between "human-readable" steps (comprising features) and actual implementation of those steps. So, you may implement these steps in a variety of ways that Java allows (or other programming language that Cucumber supports) and using the tons of 3rd party libraries like Selenium, Rest assured etc.

So, the answer is "**yes**" as long as you know the right tool / library / approach that can test Java applications

Comment: Thank you :) Ivan